# Hibernate One To Many Relation Hbm Xml Error

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to create relation between Definition (DEF) and Details (DET) table by foreign keys in Hibernate. In this case, one definition has multiple details.

- Definition table has **ID** column as *PK*
- Details table has **ID** column as *PK* and **DEFINITION_ID** as *FK*

When I connect these inside of **hbm.xml** I am getting an error such as;

## ERROR

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping
>   for entity: com.ykb.hmn.cms.commission.datamodel.ICmsExemptRestrictDet
>   column: ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

## DEFINITION HBM XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.ykb.hmn.cms.commission.datamodel.ICmsExemptRestrictDef"
        table="CMS_EXEMPT_RESTRICT_DEF">
        <tuplizer class="com.ykb.hmn.inf.core.datamodel.IntfEntityTuplizer"
            entity-mode="pojo" />
        <id name="oid" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">SEQ_CMS_EXEMPT_RESTRICT_DEF</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        .
        .
        .

        <bag name="cmsExemptRestrictDetails" table="CMS_EXEMPT_RESTRICT_DET"
            inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="DEFINITION_ID" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many
                class="com.ykb.hmn.cms.commission.datamodel.ICmsExemptRestrictDet" />
        </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

## DETAIL HBM XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.ykb.hmn.cms.commission.datamodel.ICmsExemptRestrictDet"
        table="CMS_EXEMPT_RESTRICT_DET">
        <tuplizer class="com.ykb.hmn.inf.core.datamodel.IntfEntityTuplizer"
            entity-mode="pojo" />
        <id name="oid" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">SEQ_CMS_EXEMPT_RESTRICT_DET</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <many-to-one name="cmsExemptRestrictDefinition" class="com.ykb.hmn.cms.commission.datamodel.ICmsExemptRestrictDef" fetch="select">
            <column name="ID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>

        <property name="definitionId" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="DEFINITION_ID" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

First - Do I need to define both many to one and one to many relation in each hbm xmls?

Second - Do I need to rename column ID of Detail something like DETAIL_ID?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The property mapping  Definition_id is incorrect. The foreign key should not be mapped. Remove it and change the column name in manytoone mapping to definition_id:

Change the detail hbm xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.ykb.hmn.cms.commission.datamodel.ICmsExemptRestrictDet"
        table="CMS_EXEMPT_RESTRICT_DET">
        <tuplizer class="com.ykb.hmn.inf.core.datamodel.IntfEntityTuplizer"
            entity-mode="pojo" />
        <id name="oid" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">SEQ_CMS_EXEMPT_RESTRICT_DET</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <many-to-one name="cmsExemptRestrictDefinition" class="com.ykb.hmn.cms.commission.datamodel.ICmsExemptRestrictDef" fetch="select">
            <column name="DEFINITION_ID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>

           </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```